# Split output result by n and loop

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, oledb

I'm solving an issue where I need to create one PDF form.

That PDF form has 8 sections where I need to put info about and looks like shown on picture (only 4 shown).

The point is that my query will return 0 - n different results. So I need to split by 8 and post on different pages.

I tried like shown below but that seems not to work since I always load a new document. Does anyone have some advice how to make it?

[image]

```vb
Try
    Dim sCommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    sCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT a,b,c Query to fetch n results ", _dbCon)
    sCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
    Dim _dbREADER As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    _dbREADER = sCommand.ExecuteReader
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Load(_dbREADER)

    Dim totalPages As Integer = dt.Rows.Count / 8
    Dim currentPage As Integer = 1
    Dim rowCounter As Long = 0

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            rowCounter += 1

            If rowCounter = 8 Then
                currentPage += 1
                rowCounter = 0
            End If

            _pdfDocumentOutput = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "MailingForm_" & currentPage & ".pdf"
            SaveFromResources(_pdfDocument, My.Resources.template)

            Using reader As New PdfReader(_pdfDocument)
                Using stamper As New PdfStamper(reader, New IO.FileStream(_pdfDocumentOutput, IO.FileMode.Create))
                    Dim fontName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "SCRIPTIN.ttf")
                    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)

                    Dim pdfForm As AcroFields = stamper.AcroFields
                    pdfForm.AddSubstitutionFont(bf)
                    pdfForm.SetField(rowCounter - 1 & "0", row("Customer")) 'Checks the top radiobutton of the VrPr4 field
                    pdfForm.SetField(rowCounter - 1 & "1", row("Address"))
                    pdfForm.SetField(rowCounter - 1 & "2", row("Location"))
                    stamper.FormFlattening = True
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    End If

    Status.Text = "Store info loaded ! "
Catch ex As Exception
    Status.Text = ex.Message
End Try
```

Comment: Your question contains a contradiction. [1] you say *I need to create one PDF form.* I assume you want to create an interactive PDF from scratch that meets certain requirements. [2] that form already exists in your code. The path to that document is stored in the `_pdfDocument` variable. At that point, it's already too late to meet the desired requirements. Either they are met, or they aren't met. Given the fact that you post a question, one can assume that the requirements aren't met. [2] contradicts [1], and that makes it impossible to comment on your question, let alone answer it.

Comment: Ok sorry for my bad explanation. The point is i know i must get as output n files ? But they were all based on one _pdfDocument with diferent data in it. Since i dont have ability to recreate file and put all pages into one file so i had to use it like i shown. My anwser is an answer which solved my problem. But since its not accepted im still looking for easier way of making it. At least LINQ to split datatable instead of those for loops

Comment: No one but you can accept your own question, hence I don't understand why you say "since it's not accepted." If you need n files as output (first part of your comment), you need to create a `PdfReader` and a `PdfStamper` n times. What's the problem with that? In the second part of your comment, you seem to want to put all pages into one file. That's confusing. It's totally unclear if you want n documents or a single document.

Comment: I wanted to put all pages in one file. But is that possible at all ?? For now i accept also n documents ? About my question i think i complicated it to much and it should not be on stackoverflow

Comment: Of course it's possible to put all pages in one file. Your problem doesn't sound complicated, but you make your question so complicated that no one can answer it.

Comment: You seem to be wasting plenty of time on something that is simple. Instead of *wasting* more time, please *spend* one hour watching this webinar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLrBv0UOcsg Please watch it to the end, as it explains different scenarios filling out a form template and putting those filled out forms into one document, some of these scenarios are bad and should be avoided, so make sure you watch the full video to know which scenarios are good and which are bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by splitting tables

```
 Private Shared Function SplitTable(ByVal originalTable As DataTable, ByVal batchSize As Integer) As List(Of DataTable)
        Dim tables As List(Of DataTable) = New List(Of DataTable)()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 1
        Dim newDt As DataTable = originalTable.Clone()
        newDt.TableName = "Table_" & j
        newDt.Clear()
        For Each row As DataRow In originalTable.Rows
            Dim newRow As DataRow = newDt.NewRow()
            newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray
            newDt.Rows.Add(newRow)
            i += 1
            If i = batchSize Then
                tables.Add(newDt)
                j += 1
                newDt = originalTable.Clone()
                newDt.TableName = "Table_" & j
                newDt.Clear()
                i = 0
            End If

            If row.Equals(originalTable.Rows(originalTable.Rows.Count - 1)) Then
                tables.Add(newDt)
                j += 1
                newDt = originalTable.Clone()
                newDt.TableName = "Table_" & j
                newDt.Clear()
                i = 0
            End If
        Next

        Return tables
    End Function
```

And after that loop through each one of table . And put all results to one file

```
Dim tables = SplitTable(dt, 8)
```